# Changing two strings on same line matched by a regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a number of variables in a .dat file that I automatically changed with a script. One of these files has a parameter, `bar`, that is arranged as such in a .dat file:

```
var1  var2   var3  foo  bar
T     T      T     100  100
```

I used to use the following lines of a bash script to change the value of bar from an arbitrary initial value to the desired value, in this case 2000. This script would change 'bar' to 2000.

```
LINE1=$(awk '/bar/ {++n;if (n==1) {print FNR}}' data.dat)
((LINE1=$LINE1 + 1))
OLD1=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<'$LINE1';i++) getline}{print $12}' data.dat)
sed -i '' "${LINE1}s/$OLD1/2000/" data.dat
```

However, I now must now change `foo` alongside `bar`. In this example, this is setting `foo` and `bar` both to 2000.

```
LINE1=$(awk '/foo/ {++n;if (n==1) {print FNR}}' data.dat)
((LINE1=$LINE1 + 1))
OLD1=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<'$LINE1';i++) getline}{print $12}' data.dat)
sed -i '' "${LINE1}s/$OLD1/2000/" data.dat

LINE1=$(awk '/bar/ {++n;if (n==1) {print FNR}}' data.dat)
((LINE1=$LINE1 + 1))
OLD1=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<'$LINE1';i++) getline}{print $12}' data.dat)
sed -i '' "${LINE1}s/$OLD1/2000/" data.dat
```

This instead only changed the `foo` to 2000 while leaving `bar` unchanged. I realize that this is an issue with the way I've described the regular expression, but I have been unable to change both variables with an awk/sed expression.

Comment: Pls post the file `fort.4` so people can follow your logics. Do you want to change the `bar` text or the number `100`?

Comment: The fort.4 was an accidental insertion, the file to be edited is data.dat. The var 1/var 2/var 3/ lines are now representative of the data.dat file. I'm trying to change the arguments to `foo` and `bar` rather than the strings `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
awk -v newvalue=2000 '
    NR == 1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i == "foo") i_foo=i
            if ($i == "bar") i_bar=i
        }
    }
    NR == 2 {$i_foo = $i_bar = newvalue}
    {print}
' file.dat | column -t
```

```
var1  var2  var3  foo   bar
T     T     T     2000  2000
```

Or, with less hard-coding in the awk

```
awk -v cols="var2=1234,bar=5678" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(cols, a, /[=,]/)
        for (i=1; i<n; i+=2) newval[a[i]] = a[i+1]
    }
    NR == 1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in newval) idx[$i] = i }
    NR == 2 { for (col in idx) $(idx[col]) = newval[col] }
    {print}
' file.dat | column -t
```

```
var1  var2  var3  foo  bar
T     1234  T     100  5678
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this to in-place change file.dat?

Comment: With GNU awk `gawk -i inplace '...`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' -vfoovalue=2101 -vbarvalue=2102 '
             /foo/&&/bar/{
                           row=NR
                           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                                               if($i=="foo"){colfoo=i}
                                               if($i=="bar"){colbar=i}
                                              }
                           print
                          }
             NR==row+1{ $colfoo=foovalue; $colbar=barvalue; print }
            ' file

var1    var2    var3    foo         bar
T       T       T       2101        2102
```